# Opening tag "input" not terminated.ngtsc(-995002)

Tags: php, html, angular, date, input

```php
<input type="date" class="form-control"  value=" <?php echo date("Y-m-d");?> " >
```

I am trying to put the current date inside a date type input so that I get the current date un angular, I use php inside the input but it gives me an error. how to solve this error?

why?????...
What can i do in angular to get the current date in a input ?

[image]

Comment: You can't put php inside an html file.

Comment: Not understand why you use PHP to bind the value to HTML, as you use the Angular app, there are plenty of ways to bind value: 1. String interpolation `{{ variable }}`, 2. `ngModel`. (One, two-way binding).

Comment: Angular not transpile php :(

Comment: It's not about transpiling or other stuff. Php is a _server_  language, it cannot run in an environment such as Angular. It's just illogical & non sense even just thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax problem, I think your file type is html, if it is html you need to change it to php.
Because you used PHP code in the value section, you should convert your file extension to PHP.

> **agregar-empleado-component.html covert to agregar-empleado-component.php**